# Issue trying to get website to work - possible issue with my html code?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, ftp

SO I have code that I'm trying to implement from my jsfiddle into an actual working website/mini-app. I've registered the domain name and procured the hosting via siteground, and I've even uploaded the files via ftp so I'm almost there...

But I'm thinking there's something wrong with my HTML code or JS code or how I implemented my JS code into my HTML code, because all of the HTML and CSS elements are present, but the javascript functionality is absent.

Here is my fiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/33/)

^^ Click on start to see the display in action (which doesn't work in the actual website, which leads me to believe there's an issue with my JS file - whether it be code-related or whether that's because I integrated the file incorrectly) (or maybe even uploaded to the server incorrectly, perhaps?)...

And here is the actual site:

http://www.abveaspirations.com/index.html

And here's my HTML code uploaded to the server via FTP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id='frame'>
      <div id='display'>
        <h1 id='output'></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
    <div id="main"> <!-- 11main -->
        <h1 id='consoleTitle'>Control Board</h1>
        <h5 id='consoleSub'><i>Double-click on an entry to remove. And add entries to your heart's desire...</i></h5>
        <div id="controlbox"> <!-- @@controlbox --> 
            <div id="controlpanel"></div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>    
                <div id="formula">    <!--formula -->
                    <form id="frm" method="post">
                        <input id="txt" type="text" placeholder="Insert your own entry here..." name="text">            
                        <input id='submitBtn' type="submit" value="Start">
                        <input id='stop' type="button" value="Stop">            
                            <select id="load1">
                                <option id='pre0' value="Preset 0">Preset 0</option>
                                <option id='pre1' value="Preset 1">Preset 1</option>
                                <option id='pre2' value="Preset 2">Preset 2</option>   
                            </select>
                                        <!-- These are for buttons as opposed to OPTION...
                                        <input id="load" type="button" value="Preset 1">
                                        <input id="load2" type="button" value="Preset 2"-->
                    </form>
                </div>          <!-- formula -->   
        </div>  <!-- @@controlbox -->
    </div>        <!-- 11main -->
</body>
```

And my JS code, also uploaded to server via FTP (I didn't include the accompanying CSS file, but if that would help, I can provide ):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txtBox = $('#txt');
    var frm = $('#frm');
    var output = $('#output');
    var subBtn = $('#submitBtn');
    var stopBtn = $('#stop');
    var loadBtn = $('#load');
    var loadBtn2 = $('#load2');
    var loadBtnA = $('#load1');
    var pre0 = $('#pre0');
    var pre1 = $('#pre1');
    var pre2 = $('#pre2');
    var txt = $('#display');
    var preset1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
    var preset2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var container = ["What we do in life echoes in all eternity.", "Find your purpose and give it life.", "When you work your hardest, the world opens up to you."];
    var console = $('#controlpanel');
    var oldHandle;

    function loadPreset0() {
        container = [];
        console.empty();
        container = ["What we do in life echoes in all eternity.", "Find your purpose and give it life.", "When you work your hardest, the world opens up to you."];
        updateConsole();
    };

function loadPreset1() {
    container = [];
    console.empty();
    container = preset1;
    updateConsole();
};

function loadPreset2() {
    container = [];
    console.empty();
    container = preset2;
    updateConsole();
};



$(pre0).data('onselect', function() {
    loadPreset0();
});    

$(pre1).data('onselect', function() {
    loadPreset1();
});

$(pre2).data('onselect', function() {
    loadPreset2();
});

$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected'),
        handler = selected.data('onselect');
    if ( typeof handler == 'function' ) {
        handler.call(selected, e);
    }
});


function updateConsole() {
    for (var z = 0; z < container.length; z++) {
        var resultC = container[z];
        var $initialEntry = $('<p>' + '- ' + resultC + '</p>');
        console.append($initialEntry);
     };
};

updateConsole();


frm.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (txtBox.val() != '') {
        var result = txtBox.val();
        container.push(result);                         //1.

        var resultB = container[container.length-1];
        var $entry = $('<p>' + '- ' + resultB + '</p>');
        console.append($entry);                         //2.
    }

    var options = {
        duration: 5000,
        rearrangeDuration: 1000,
        effect: 'random',
        centered: true
    };

    stopTextualizer();
    txt.textualizer(container, options);
    txt.textualizer('start');
    txtBox.val('');
}); 



$("#controlbox").on('dblclick', 'p', function() {
    var $entry = $(this);
    container.splice($entry.index(), 1);
    $entry.remove();
});

function stopTextualizer(){
    txt.textualizer('stop');
    txt.textualizer('destroy');
}

$(stopBtn).click(function() {
    stopTextualizer();
});


});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I guess I'm just not sure what to do after uploading the html file to the server via ftp. Or maybe I did that correctly and there's something wrong with my code that I'm overlooking. Basically I'm lost. So help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load jQuery. Make sure that you use `<script src="../path-to-jquery/jquery.js"></script>` before you load your `script.js` script.

Also, I noticed that you're loading your scripts in the `head` tag. This is bad practice, load them right before `</body>`.

Comment: Ahhhh! I knew it was something basic that I just completely overlooked. THANKS!!!

Comment: Big thank you that worked. I also forgot to include the plugin script. When changing the script or index.html file - what's the best and recommended way to do it (should I make changes to code thru my server's file manager? or update the actual file through my text editor and then update via filezilla? or maybe thru github?)?...

Comment: Very welcome, that's the beauty of Stack. Some time ago I used FTP, but recently switched to Git because I saw the light of version control. FTP is obviously easier, and Git requires both experience and shell access... but I loved the functionality of Git. I would never update directly on the server unless there was an important & quick change as I wanted to keep it a push-up workflow instead of a syncing disaster.

Comment: Ok thanks Albert - I have a little bit of experience w/ Github and the console. What's the quickest way to go from (changes on github) to (uploading those changes to the server) though? I definitely need to dive into this...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your site is missing jQuery. Add this to the top of your code to hotlink to google's jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```